# How to create an image slide with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I am using a plugin on WordPress and I need to customise the php. This is the page: https://levels-ventures.com/buying/ and instead of one image displaying I would like this to be a slider.

This is the code I have:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="es-property-inner">
    <div class="es-property-thumbnail">
        <div class="es-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php if ( ! empty( $es_property->gallery ) ) : ?>
                    <?php es_the_post_thumbnail( 'es-image-size-archive' ); ?>
                <?php elseif ( $image = es_get_default_thumbnail( 'es-image-size-archive' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php echo $image; ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="es-thumbnail-none">
                        <?php if ( ! $es_property->get_labels_list() ) : ?>
                            <?php _e( 'No image', 'es-plugin' ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( $es_settings->show_labels ) : ?>
                    <ul class="es-property-label-wrap">
                        <?php foreach ( $es_property->get_labels_list() as $label ) : $value = $es_property->{$label->slug}; ?>
                            <?php if ( ! empty( $value ) ) : ?>
                                <li class="es-property-label es-property-label-<?php echo $label->slug; ?>"
                                    style="color:<?php echo es_get_the_label_color( $label->term_id ); ?>"><?php _e( $label->name, 'es-plugin' ) ; ?></li><br>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $es_property->gallery ) && is_array( $es_property->gallery ) ) : ?>
                    <div class="es-thumbnail-bottom"><?php echo count( $es_property->gallery ); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does anything know how to change this so instead of displaying one image it displayes a slider of images?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hi Francesca,

This Javascript library can help you with sliders:https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap's `Carousel`. Very simple to implement with slider. Please refer to their official website [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)